# Absolute Value in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have an Game Property called **Speed** (it is an Integer). I want to use that property to display the speed that my vehicle is going on a speedometer. When the vehicle is going in reverse, the speed value becomes negative, seriously confusing the poor gauge. How can I make the Integer **Speed** always positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler method using the often overlooked feature of expressions in logic bricks.

[image: logic bricks]
I have a *Always* Sensor (True level triggering enabled) driving a *Property* actuator. That property actuator is assigning my "speed display" game property the value of my speed. The trick is in the *Value* field `if (speed<0, speed*-1, speed)`. It's just a simple if statement. If the speed is less then zero (negative), invert it, else just copy the speed.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by having two integer properties. One called **SpeedRaw** and another called **SpeedCorrected** - the names really do not matter, you will be fine as long as you know which is which.

You simply need to check if **SpeedRaw** is negative. If it is, it will assign **SpeedCorrected** the value of **SpeedRaw** *-1. If **SpeedRaw** is positive, **SpeedCorrected** will simply be the same as **SpeedRaw**.

[image: This is for all those fun little crawler bots out there - Hi everybody!!!:-) (If you can see this, the image didn't load properly)]

The end result works as follows:

[image: ![enter image description here]

This also works for float values, however the second property sensor needs to detect when **SpeedRaw** is greater than 0, not -1.